# Android JSON parse error with date

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Having problems parsing this JSON data in my Android App :

```
[{"personid":20,"personName":"Ross Gallagher update3","email":"ross_gallagher@rossgallagher.co.uk","birthday":{"date":"2013-01-01 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/Los_Angeles"},"anniversary":{"date":"1900-01-01 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/Los_Angeles"},"Credit":2}]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"birthday":{"date":"2013-01-01 00:00:00","timezone":"America\/Los_Angeles","timezone_type":3},"anniversary":{"date":"1900-01-01 00:00:00","timezone":"America\/Los_Angeles","timezone_type":3},"email":"ross_gallagher@rossgallagher.co.uk","personName":"Ross Gallagher update8","Credit":2,"personid":20}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

My JSON Parser code is:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url)
{
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    JSONObject respObject = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(httpEntity != null){
        try {
            respObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //....
    }
    // return JSON
    return respObject;
}
```

All I need is to pull out the Birthday details from this JSON object along with the name, email, credits and anniversary.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
respObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
```

to

```
respObject = new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
```

ofcourse respObject has  to be an `JSONArray`

Comment: Thanks, I completely blanked over the [ ] as every other response from our API was a plain JSONObject not a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your JSON String. You need to remove the square brakets **[]** .
Square brakets are used to refer array elements. The JSON parser will try to convert it as array object as json data are inside square braket.

Accept my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Since the object you are trying to parse is actually a JSONArray and not JSONObject.. So you get JSONObject from that JSONArray like

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));

JSONOject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

from this jsonObject  you would get birthday details...